# changing web content but still google analytics tracks the page

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics

Here is a website `a` let say a.com with `a.com/xxx` or `/yyy`
I am now the webmaster and i don't know the initial setup of the web.
It used google analytics to track webpage info. 
And it is assumed the web is attached with javascript tracking code.

The webpage reforms and it is now with no tracking code.
However, there is still tracking info until today.
Some of the hierarchy of the website remains.

Q1. Why google can still track the website? 
I guess that's because of the unchanged hierarchy.

Q2. Can i see individual user pathway / history? Now i can see the summary of each day / hour with total. What I want is user a `/xxx -> /yyy` / `a.com -> /yyy`

Q3. I still want to use google analytics service. How can I make sure it works fine?
 Status now: receiving data, which I barely trust. Answer of Q2 leads to Q3.
If I can see there are some users viewing the new page e.g. `a.com/zzz`, then i know new webpage is being tracked.

Newbie to web.
Comment appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because it belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most possibly your tracking code is in your header or footer, so every new page will have it. Just look for the code in the source code. 
It doesn't matter if you change a content, structure, make new page or whatsoever. Google Analytics tracks every page where the code is present, and don't track pages where there is no code.

If there is no tracking code (and you are sure there isn't) - then GA can't track it. However there are spam referrals, that could hit your GA account and show you traffic on pages where the code is missing (just check if the traffic is referral). To fight with this spam you need a filters but this is whole new question.